# How to know when another Cocoa app paste an item that you put into the general pasteboard

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa, nspasteboard

In a Mac OS X app (Cocoa), I'm copying an item into the general pasteboard `NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()`. The item makes use of an object that implements the protocol `NSPasteboardItemDataProvider`, to provide the data when the user pastes it using another app.

Depending on the type chosen by the destination app, some temporal work (as writing a file to a temp file) can be done.

Is there a way to detect when this operation is done or canceled, so I can do some cleaning after (as removing the previously created temp file)?

As an example, I use the same data provider for dragging copy/paste operations. Adopting `NSDraggingSource` protocol, I implement the method 
`- draggingSession:endedAtPoint:operation:` to know when to do the cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

The `NSPasteboardItemDataProvider` protocol has the method `-pasteboardFinishedWithDataProvider:` for this purpose. It is called to give you an opportunity to clean up.

Is that not sufficient for some reason?

Comment: That method gets executed when the pasteboard is taken by another copy/paste operation, probably when someone calls `pasteboard.clearContents()`. I would like to be notified when the user pastes the item instead (this can happen multiple times), if it's possible.

Comment: For promised data, that method will also be called the first time something pastes the item because, once the pasteboard server has the data, it doesn't need your provider any more. There's no mechanism to be informed every time something pastes the data. Once the pasteboard server has the data, it directly satisfies future requests for it without involving your app.

Comment: The method is not called at the moment you say, but when other process clears the pasteboard to perform an operation. Also, the other assumption you're making is also incorrect, given that a data provider can provide multiple types and it doesn't have to be the same in each paste operation after you have copied it.

Comment: If it's not being called, you may be doing something wrong. From the docs: "This method is called when the pasteboard no longer needs the data provider for any of its pasteboard items. This can be either because the data provider has fulfilled all promises, or because ownership of the pasteboard has changed."

Comment: As I said in the previous comment, it gets called always when the ownership of the pasteboard has changed. When you copy something, you may want to paste it more than once, in more than one place, or even using different types, if the provider allows it (which is the case).

Comment: Pasting the same type to more than one place is not handled by the provider. The provider only provides the data once. After that the pasteboard server caches it. With regard to multiple types, that's covered by "because the data provider has fulfilled all promises". If it has promised multiple types and not all of them have been requested, then it's not done. But if all types have been requested at least once, it will be told to clean up.

Comment: You asked specifically about cleaning up. "Is there a way to detect when this operation is done or canceled, so I can do some cleaning after …?" This is the method precisely for that purpose. It's exactly what you asked for.

Comment: "The provider only provides the data once". That's not correct. Example: I copy an item (setting the data provider and writing it in the pasteboard). Then, I paste the data twice, in different destinations (requesting different types). The provider is executed twice. The delegate method you say doesn't get executed yet, it will do it later. Anyway, thanks for your help, if I can't find something better, I will keep track of the temp work I do and clean it when that method is called. I want to see how it works in a dragging session or if the user quits the app in the middle of an operation.

Comment: Right, for different types, it's called multiple times. For any given type, it's only called once. You omitted part of what I wrote to make it seem like I said something else. I wrote "Pasting **the same type** to more than one place is not handled by the provider. The provider only provides the data once." (Emphasis added.)